# Adding dynamic checkboxes android forcecloses Android

Tags: android, checkbox, forceclose, buttonbar

i've been trying to make an app with a buttonbar with add/exit buttons at the bottom, and a EditText at the top.

when i hit the add button i want the app to add checkboxes with the text from the EditText.

but when i try to launch the app it force closes.

the logcat show absolutely nothing from my app,
the console says:

```
[2014-06-24 18:41:06 - CheckList] Starting activity com.pzayx.checklist.CheckList on device 7a0ec297
[2014-06-24 18:41:06 - CheckList] ActivityManager: WARNING: linker: app_process has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
[2014-06-24 18:41:06 - CheckList] ActivityManager: WARNING: linker: app_process has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
[2014-06-24 18:41:07 - CheckList] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.pzayx.checklist/.CheckList }
[2014-06-24 18:41:07 - CheckList] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.pzayx.checklist' on port 8960
```

i cant seem to find much information about "app_process has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix" and suspect the demonspawn lies there.

here is the source of the CheckList.java

```
package com.pzayx.checklist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class CheckList extends Activity {

LinearLayout lil = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearMain);    
EditText mTextInput;
int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_check_list);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new     PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    setupWidgets();
}

private void setupWidgets() {
    mTextInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);


    Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(addListener);
    Button exitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_exit);
        exitBtn.setOnClickListener(exitListener);
}

private OnClickListener addListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doSaveButtonPress();
    }
};

private OnClickListener exitListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doExitButtonPress();
    }
};

public void doSaveButtonPress() {
    String text = mTextInput.getText().toString();
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
    cb.setId(i);
    cb.setText(text);
    lil.addView(cb);
    mTextInput.setText("");
    i++;
}

public void doExitButtonPress() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit Application?");
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            moveTaskToBack(true);
                            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                            System.exit(1);
                        }
                    })

            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

And here is my layout source

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_below="@+id/LinearMain"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutButtons"
style="?android:buttonBarStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:showDividers="middle" >

  <!--   <requestFocus /> -->


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_add"
    style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/add"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

 <View
        android:id="@+id/ViewColorPickerHelper"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_exit"
    style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/exit"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

 <!--  Checkbox Area -->

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/LinearMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="420dip"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/editText"
    android:ems="10" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

would appreciate it if anyone could help me make some sense out of it!

Thank you!

Comment: what is this?LinearLayout lil = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearMain);  the app should crash before you begin to add textview. You have not inflated the view yet

Comment: yeah, it crashed before it even launches. i'm new to android development, but now i know what to search for. Thank you!